# onload is not firing with createObjectURL img.src in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, blob, filereader

I have the following code. It works totally fine, and as expected, in Chrome. However, in Firefox it logs "CONVERT" but never "LOADED". No JS errors or anything. onload just doesn't fire. I can't seem to find much on google or stackoverflow. Many say onload doesn't fire for cached images, but these shouldn't be cached and even if they were, I wouldnt be able to cache bust them (right?)

```
  flattenImage: function(file, callback){
    // Safari uses webkitURL
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var canPreformat = !!(window.Blob && window.Uint8Array && URL && URL.createObjectURL);

    // If we have all features we need to preformat on the client and the image
    // isn't already flattened (jpeg), DO IT
    if (canPreformat && !file.type.test(/jpe?g/i)) {
      console.log('CONVERT');
      var thiz = this;
      var c = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
      var img = new Image;
      // Makes a blob URL from the file given.
      img.onload = function() {
        console.log('LOADED');
        c.width = this.width;
        c.height = this.height;

        // Take the img that was added and copy it to the canvas
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // Put the image on top of everything else
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';

        // Any transparency should become white (instead of the default black)
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        // Save canvas as a base64'd jpeg
        var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

        // The following blob lines take the base64 encoded image and then
        // convert it to a jpeg "file". This allows us to do a real file
        // upload rather than needing to send a base64 string.
        var blobBin = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]);
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < blobBin.length; i++) {
          array.push(blobBin.charCodeAt(i));
        }
        callback.call(thiz, new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'}));
      }
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
    // If we don't have all the features just return the same file given to us
    else {
      console.log('NOPE')
      callback.call(this, file);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you try setting it as an attribute? img.setAttribute('src', URL.createObjectURL(file));

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference :(

Comment: Okay, this seems to be a bug in Firefox, I am actually working with URLs from blobs as well, and even when loaded in the DOM the load event doesn't fire. I have filed a couple of blob related issues with Firefox, so this might be another one.

Comment: Does work whether you listen for the event in JS or add it as an attribute on the element, so must be on how it handles resolving the request.

Comment: Thats good/bad to know ;) do you have any ideas on work arounds for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Doesn't seem clear to me.

Comment: @joseeight See my answer below on how I got around it. Anyway, this code is so that we can flatten the image (i.e. remove layers and transparency) before uploading to file storage service that resizes images and stuff. Problem is, when it resizes images like gifs/pngs it freaks out and inverts colors and makes the alpha channels black.

Comment: Nice workaround, I would definitely file a bug with Firefox about this issue though, it should be fixed for the rest of us ;)

Comment: A bug was just filed for it, FYI: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=952179

Comment: I am experiencing this issue in Opera 31 too.

Comment: Update: Never mind. It looks like I have some issues in other parts of my system.

Answer (score 3):

I got around this issue by not using createObjectURL and instead use FileReader like this:

```
flattenImage: function(file, callback){
    // Safari uses webkitURL
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var canPreformat = !!(window.FileReader && window.Blob && window.Uint8Array);

    // If we have all features we need to preformat on the client and the image
    // isn't already flattened (jpeg), DO IT
    if (canPreformat && !file.type.test(/jpe?g/i)) {
      console.log('CONVERT');
      var thiz = this;
      var c = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

      var reader = new FileReader();
      var img = new Image;

      // Once the image is loaded from FileReader set the src of the image to
      // the base64'd result. This will trigger the img.onload
      reader.onload = function (ev) {
        img.src = ev.target.result;
      };

      // Makes a blob URL from the file given.
      img.onload = function() {
        console.log('LOADED');
        c.width = this.width;
        c.height = this.height;

        // Take the img that was added and copy it to the canvas
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // Put the image on top of everything else
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';

        // Any transparency should become white (instead of the default black)
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        // Save canvas as a base64'd jpeg
        var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

        // The following blob lines take the base64 encoded image and then
        // convert it to a jpeg "file". This allows us to do a real file
        // upload rather than needing to send a base64 string.
        var blobBin = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]);
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < blobBin.length; i++) {
          array.push(blobBin.charCodeAt(i));
        }
        callback.call(thiz, new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'}));
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    // If we don't have all the features just return the same file given to us
    else {
      callback.call(this, file);
    }
  }
```